# OS - Difference between NX bit and Valid-Invalid Bit

Tags: operating-system, segmentation-fault, paging

#### What i understand:

Setting the NX bit high for a page will mean that whenever some program tries to execute the code in that page, it will cause a segmentation fault.

There is *also* a Valid-Invalid bit, and accessing a page marked *Invalid* will also cause a segmentation fault.

#### So the question is:

Why is the NX bit not redundant when you already have a valid-invalid bit ? What does it mean to mark a page both Valid *and* NX ?

Comment: Something in the memory can be valid but not executable, which is usually called "data".

Comment: @user3528438 So is this a possible scenario:  A program reads the code(as it's marked valid, so it's OK for reading), store it somewhere with NX bit turned off, and then execute it ?

Comment: I guess so, but you will need some high privilege to manipulate NX bit, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I am going to change the terminology slightly. Instead of using terms like valid/invalid, I am going to replace them with present/not present.

A page that is marked as present can be accessed in some fashion (read, write or execute).  A page that is marked as not present is not directly accessible (if at all).  If it can be accessed, it must first be loaded from some type of backing store (disk/flash/...) into memory.

The NX bit only controls whether the page of memory has execute permissions.  Why is controlling the execute permissions important?  It helps in locking down the system to help prevent the execution of arbitrary code.

So, a page that is marked as both NX and not present is one that does not have execute permissions, but may need to be loaded from backing store.

If you do not have an NX bit (especially on your data pages), then if some clever hacker figures out how to jump to code in the data section while in supervisor/kernel mode, it makes their job much easier to execute arbitrary code on your system.

Hope this helps.